# How to determine if a character is alphanumeric using comparison operator?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking freecodecamp challenge "Check for Palindromes". Write a function to check if a given string is palindrome. Here is my code:

```
    function palindrome(str) {
      str = str.toLowerCase();
      for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if((str[i] > 'z' || str[i] < 'a') && (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')){
          str = str.replace(str[i], '');
        }
      }
      for(i=0; i<str.length/2; i++){
        if(str[i] != str[str.length-1-i]){
        return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

But it not worked properly. When I use `replace(/[\W_]/g, '');` :

```
    function palindrome(str) {
      str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]/g, '');
 //   for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
 //     if((str[i] > 'z' || str[i] < 'a') && (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')){
 //       str = str.replace(str[i], '');
 //     }
 //   }
      for(i=0; i<str.length/2; i++){
      if(str[i] != str[str.length-1-i]){
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
```

The function worked properly. Is my first method not correct?

Comment: could you give some sample input + output

Comment: Yes, your first snippet is incorrect. It mutates the string - shortening it - whilst iterating it.

Comment: @cartant I get it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jonasw palindrome("race car") should return true.
palindrome("not a palindrome") should return false.

Answer (score 0):

Palindromes ignore capitalization, spaces, punctuation and newlines and so on.

So:

A man. A plan. A canal: Panama!

Is a valid palindrome.

As such, you need to strip all punctuation and whitespace out of your string before trying to evaluate it, such that the string you're actually evaluating is:

amanaplanacanalpanama

Then it's easy to do whatever comparator you'd like on the remaining characters.

I did one of these a while ago and included some tests, it might be worth looking at: https://github.com/pvencill/palindrome